# Does my web login system work?

Tags: authentication, security

I'm building a web login system for a website without SSL, so here is my implement:
I have a table in server that has two fields, a raw username and pass_hashed (hased with sha1(password)). 
When ever the user login to my system, I do:

1. generate a key.
2. password_hashed = sha1(key + sha1(password))
3. submit 3 value: username, key, password_hashed

In the server side:

1. check if the key was stored in database, if yes, make the login invalid else save the key to database.
2. query for the user info base on username, and then compare sha1(key + pass_hased) and password_hashed.

My question is my method is ok? If yes, can I use the key as timestamp?

Comment: `I'm building a web login system for a website without SSL`  It is completely impossible to make that secure.  Use SSL.  http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/  http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/29/final-post-on-javascript-crypto/

Comment: Other than the fact that it won't help, that is a secure design, except that SHA1 is too brute-forceable (use PBKDFv2).  Also, note that anyone who steals your database can impersonate any user (on your site only)

Comment: Thanks for your great comments. Infact my clinet is a C++ progam not web browser, but you are right about impersonate issue...

Comment: That's a completely separate issue; you should edit your question.  How do you know that users aren't getting a trojaned copy of the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your solution is better than nothing it is ultimately flawed. This is because at some point during the user's registration process they need to send only a portion of the information. If the information is captured over the wire at that point any login can be repeated later.

You really need SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the combination seems to be okay. Would you like to use timestamp for generating key?

If that's so, you may start with it but try different combinations that help in increasing the security.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users, the system you have implemented is not secure and may result in security issue. If you are gathering customer's information, you must use SSL certificate. It won't cost more. its start from as low as $7 !!